# Share iPhone screen for MacBook wirelessly?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, sharing, screen-capture, screen-sharing

Is it possible to share the screen of my iPhone on my MacBook wirelessly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AirPlay's Screen Mirroring on the iPhone to mirror the display to your Mac running AirPlay server software such as [**Reflector**](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) or [**AirServer**](https://www.airserver.com/Mac). With the software installed on your Mac, open Control Center, choose Screen Mirroring and select your Mac to begin mirroring.

Comment: Thank you very much! Are there also any free solutions?